# How do I make Snoopy angry?

Tags: ios, snoopys-street-fair

In Snoopy's Street Fair for iPhone, one of your goals is to make Snoopy angry ten times.

I tried just tapping him to get various reactions hoping that one of them would be anger, since that approach worked when I had to make him laugh ten times.

However, I have now seen every emotional reaction Snoopy has, multiple times, but it still shows no progress towards the goal of making him angry ten times. I know it doesn't have to be consecutive, but beyond that, I don't know what to do.

How do I make Snoopy angry?

Comment: You don't want to make Snoopy angry. You [wouldn't like him](http://www.google.com/search?q=lou+ferrigno+hulk&tbm=isch) when he's angry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wake him up while he is sleeping on his dog house